# Does INSERT INTO on a Hive external table insert the row to the underlying HDFS dataset as well?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs

I have a Hive **external** table 'customer_main' mapped to an .orc-based HDFS dataset that has the path '/dev/customer/customer_main/'. If I run an INSERT INTO customer_main VALUES() to insert a row into the customer_main Hive table, will this row be appended to the corresponding HDFS dataset in /dev/customer/customer_main as well? Or will this insertion be restricted to the Hive table only?

Comment: Try it? Hive itself doesn't have a storage engine

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is Yes.
Hive just stores the location of the table & when you do an insert it will put a new file with the record in that table location.

While reading it will read all the data files irrespective of what is the source of those files.